# Copy / paste multiple cells from one workbook into another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am trying to copy / paste multiple cells from one workbook into another.

The macro searches for bold text in Column H and copies the hours on the right side. I need them in Workbook 2 Column X2 and the following rows under it but the formula is inserting the column into X19 and is replacing the old one with the new ones.

The searching and copy / paste formula:

```vb
Dim startRow As Long

Dim RA As Range
Dim checkcell As Range
Dim dest As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Schichtplan")
ws.Range("X2:AI200").Delete

Set src = Workbooks.Open("P:\resource*" & ".xlsx") 'resourceshiftcalplanningmatrix.xlsx

Set dest = ThisWorkbook

Set RA = Range("H18:H100")

For Each checkcell In RA
    If checkcell.Font.Bold = True Then

        checkcell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1:L1").Copy

        With ws
            .Cells(Range("X25").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 24).PasteSpecial
        End With

    End If
Next checkcell
```

The two workbooks:

From:
[image: Workbook resourceshiftcal...]

Blacked out information that shouldn't be shown.

To:
[image: Workbook where the "Schichtplan" is in]

Comment: `Range("X25").End(xlUp).Row + 1` does not refer to `ws`. If you want it to refer to `ws`, you need a `.` in front of `Range`.

Comment: Ouh gawd, thank you very much i was frustrated because i didnt see that in the slightest

Answer (score 0):

The .Range("X25") solved the problem immediatly.

```
With ws

.Cells(.Range("X25").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 24).PasteSpecial

End With
```

Comment: Alternately `.Range("X25").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial`.